# Searching folders by folder path in EWS using SOAP

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is it possible to do a SOAP search by PR_FOLDER_PATH?  A simple search for any folder with "Inbox" in the path comes up empty:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FindFolder Traversal="Deep" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:FolderClass" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="4340" PropertyType="Boolean" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="26293" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </FolderShape>
      <Restriction>
        <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="26293" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:Constant Value="Inbox" />
        </t:Contains>
      </Restriction>
      <ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="msgfolderroot" />
      </ParentFolderIds>
    </FindFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Indeed, PR_FOLDER_PATH seems to be a bit of a mystery.  I know its property tag is 26293 and I can see folder path values output in other search results.  But I can't seem to find a way to even get values for this property listed in the EWS Editor, never mind having it work with search filters.  What's the PID name equivalent? PR_FOLDER_PATH isn't even listed in MS-OXPROPS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its a computed property and is only valid in EWS in the FindFolder Operation because of the underlying Exchange operations that returns this (eg it won't work in a GetFolder operation in 2013 up).

An easy way to achieve what you want is just make the FindFolder on the Inbox which will give you all the folders with Inbox in the Path. For user created folders you will need to find the Id for the user created folder but it works similarly.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: So you're saying I'm not getting an error or results because it's "not implemented", in other words?? Essentially I need to get the ID for a folder and all I have it the DisplayName and folder path (obtained from a previous deep traversal FindFolder operation). Regardless, a working alternative is to filter on DisplayName and iterate through the results to match on the folder path. I'm just hoping for a cleaner way

Comment: My approach has always been if you have the path split that out into its components and find the root folder, and each subfolder making separate shallow searches which has always worked. (Personally i think this is quicker then making a deep traversal where on a Mailbox with more than a 1000 folder is going to be troublesome).

Comment: Good point! I'm going down this path precisely because one of my beta testers has 1400 folders and has forced me to rethink my folder caching mechanism completely. I was actually just coding up a FindFolder operation but I'll throw it away now and use your suggestion. Thanks Glen! (FYI, see http://www.rockinsoftware.ca/MessageFiler.html if you're curious; my blog has a video of it as well)